# Dart/Flutter verification/validation on Firebase Firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a Dart/Flutter verification/validation on Firebase Firestore database to not save the same serial number string twice in the database, but I'm doing something wrong.

Code

```
   DocumentSnapshot snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection("lockers").document() as DocumentSnapshot;
   if (snapshot.data["numero_serie"]  == "$_numeroSerie"){
      print("QR Code ja cadastrado");
    } else {
      await Firestore.instance
          .collection("lockers")
          .document()
          .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
    }
  }
```

Firebase firestore
[image: firebase]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler Way Would be:

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection("lockers")
    .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
    .limit(1)
    .getDocuments());

final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
if (documents.length == 1) {
  print("QR Code ja cadastrado");
} else {
  await Firestore.instance
       .collection("lockers")
       .document()
       .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
}
```

Comment: I have just one problem, the message ("QR Code ja cadastrado") apper just the the first repeat, if i try repeat more times, don't appear the message, you know how can solve this ?

Comment: Because we are simply checking it if in any document it is present - and we have limit of 1 in our call - `.limit(1)` - no need to check it against each document as we are simply want to check if its there in collection or not.

Comment: if i have a compound query    `final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
        .collection("lockers")
        .where("userid", isEqualTo: "$_uid")
        .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
        .getDocuments()); ` how i can limit this ?

Comment: `final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
        .collection("lockers")
        .where("userid", isEqualTo: "$_uid")
        .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie").limit(1)
        .getDocuments());`